# WCF как оповестить хост о закрытии клиента

Tags: wcf

как оповестить хост о закрытии клиента?
вот клиент

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Windows;
using Host;

namespace VideoPlayer
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IContractCallback
{
    private IContractServer Proxy = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
        DuplexChannelFactory<IContractServer> factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IContractServer>(context, new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost");
        Proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Proxy.Connect(true);
    }

    public void ConnectCallback(bool status)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(status ? "connected" : "no connected");
    }

    public void PlayCallback(bool status)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("status true");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("status false");
        }
    }


    private void ButtonPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Proxy.Play(true);
    }


    private void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //хочу отправить сообщение о закрытии
        Proxy.Disconnect(Proxy);
    }
```

вот контракт

```
  [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IContractCallback))]
public interface IContractServer
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Connect(bool status);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    void Disconnect(IContractServer _channelCallback);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Play(bool status);
}
```

вот сервис

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : IContractServer
{
    public List<IContractCallback> _channeList = new List<IContractCallback>();

    public void Connect(bool status)
    {
        IContractCallback a = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IContractCallback>();
        int call = 0;
        foreach (var callBack in _channeList)
        {
            if (callBack == a)
            {
                call++;
            }
        }

        if (call == 0)
        {
            _channeList.Add(a);
            a.ConnectCallback(true);
        }
        else
        {
            a.ConnectCallback(false);
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect(IContractServer _channelCallback)
    {
        foreach (var contractCallback in _channeList)
        {
            if (contractCallback == _channelCallback)
            {
                _channeList.Remove(contractCallback);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Play(bool status)
    {
        foreach (var contractCallback in _channeList)
        {
            contractCallback.PlayCallback(status);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый канал WCF реализует  `ICommunicationObject`, который имеет события для определения времени жизни канала.

Вы должны наблюдать за событием `Faulted`.

Доступ к `SessionId` обычно можно получить из свойства `OperationContext.Current`.

Когда ваш клиент открывает канал([первая операция](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isinitiating(v=vs.110).aspx)) выполняйте подписывание на событие:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += new EventHandler(Channel_Faulted);
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += new EventHandler(Channel_Faulted);
```

и

```
void Channel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Logout((IContextChannel)sender);
 }

 protected void Logout(IContextChannel channel)
 {
        string sessionId = null;



  if (channel != null)
        {
            sessionId = channel.SessionId;
        }
      [...]
 }
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338842/detect-socket-disconnect-in-wcf)